# Macro Overloading with Different Signatures

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

Is it possible to overload macros that can perform different operators (=, +=, -=, ++, --, etc) with the same macro name?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
int main() {
    LOG_STAT("hello") << "world";
    LOG_STAT("hello") = 5;
    LOG_STAT("hello") += 10;
}
```

I tried the following and the issue I am having is that I can not redeclare the macro LOG_STAT as it has already been defined. Sample code below, hopefully you get the idea.

```
#define LOG_STAT(x) Stat(x).streamAdd()

#define LOG_STAT(x) Stat(x).add() // redeclare error here

class Stat {

    public:
        Stat(const char *type_ ) : type(type_) {}
        ~Stat(){ std::cout << type << " " << stream.str().c_str() << " " << number << std::endl;}

        int& add() { return number; }
        std::ostringstream& streamAdd() { return stream; }

        const char * type;
        int number;
        std::ostringstream stream;
};
```

Comment: What is `LOG_STAT("hello") += 10;` supposed to mean? Especially with `LOG_STAT(...)` being a `std::ostream`..

Comment: Macros are evil. Create a class which overloads these operators to do what you want if you must.

Comment: @BillLynch is just another example of overloading. For example, the += would increase number within the stat class. In the example above the value would be 15 when called by the destructor.

Comment: @NeilKirk ya, I think you are right the more I think about it. I was just curious to see if something like this _could_ be possible.

Comment: Macros happen, conceptually at least, a long time before the compiler understands operators. So no, you can't do that for macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create operators for your class:

```
Stat& Stat::operator += (int rhs)
{
    number += rhs;
    return *this;
}

Stat operator + (const Stat& lhs, int rhs)
{
    Stat res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
Stat& operator << (Stat& stat, const T&value)
{
    stat.stream << value;
    return stat;
}
```

Then you may directly use

```
Stat("hello") << "world";
Stat("hello") = 5;
Stat("hello") += 10;
```

(You may still use your MACRO with `#define LOG_STAT Stat`)